# Ubuntu 16.04 problems connecting to eduroam

Tags: wireless, 16.04

Using Ubuntu 16.04 and have been connected to my UNI's eduroam wifi fine till a week ago. Now it keeps asking for my password and wont connect.

Have tried workarounds from other similar questions asked but no joy.

Help!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I removed the old connection and set up a new one manually which worked for me.

To remove the old connection, I removed the file named "eduroam" in the directory "/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections".

You may set up Eduroam manually as follows: type "sudo nm-connection-editor" in terminal. Punch you password, if asked for. This opens the connection editor. Now fill in the details along with your credentials as you would have done for a usual setup. That is all.

If you want, you may use gedit or nano and create a new connection in the above mentioned repository.

I am not sure, but you might have to log out and log in again to get connected.

However, I do not know why this worked and the usual set up did not!

Answer (score 2):

I followed the instructions linked [here](http://wiki.cs.huji.ac.il/wiki/Wireless/eduroam), in the GUI section.  Everything worked fine on 16.04.  Here's a copy of my resulting config file found in: `etc/NetworkManager/system-conenctions/eduroam` (my personal info has been replaced or blacked out).

```
[connection]
id=eduroam
uuid=9bcf5de0-d802-424f-bc67-80cfd6df1cda
type=wifi
permissions=user:yourUserName:;
secondaries=

[wifi]
mac-address=**:**:**:**:**:**
mac-address-blacklist=
mac-address-randomization=0
mode=infrastructure
seen-bssids=
ssid=eduroam

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
group=
key-mgmt=wpa-eap
pairwise=
proto=

[802-1x]
altsubject-matches=
ca-cert=/etc/ssl/certs/AddTrust_External_Root.pem
eap=peap;
identity=studentnumber@university.com
password=PasswordForStudentNumber
phase2-altsubject-matches=
phase2-auth=mschapv2

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

Answer (score 1):

At some point, probably after upgrading to Ubuntu 15 or 16, I became unable to connect to eduroam with my laptop.

After trying a lot of possible solutions, I found that all my problem was due to the nl80211 driver that was not working. Finally I could solve all my problems [following an Arch Linux guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#nl80211_driver_not_supported_on_some_hardware).

Although in my system I had to add the wext driver in `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant.service`. I simply included `-Dnl80211,wext` to the `Exec` line. So that the whole file is now:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant
Exec=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u  -Dnl80211,wext  -O /run/wpa_supplicant
User=root
SystemdService=wpa_supplicant.service
```

With this I can connect to eduroam again!

Comment: Could you please cite *all the crucial parts* of  external resources (not just your modifications) in case they change or disappear? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, there exists a configuration assistant tool available for all major OSes here https://cat.eduroam.org/.  The tool itself is a python script that sets a connection and creates the necessary certificate.