# Cannot connect to Eduroam

Tags: networking, connection

I recently changed my password for my school network and I have not been able to connect to the Eduroam connections since then.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Here are a few things I tried:

- [Ubuntu 16.04 problems connecting to eduroam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788472/ubuntu-16-04-problems-connecting-to-eduroam)
- [How do I connect to eduroam on Linux?](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=152599592)
- [How do I connect to eduroam using Linux (Ubuntu 11.10)?](https://wiki.umbc.edu/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=31199057)

It worked just fine before I updated my password. Please note that I don't see any file named Eduroam if I `cd` to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` which was suggested by many people in the posts that I read.

Answer (score 3):

We use eduroam at the university where I work; I connect to it myself when our primary wifi is being awkward.  If you've definitely removed the previous connections, try the following connection settings; this is lifted from our intranet so it's what we're telling students now:

```
Wireless Security: WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
Authentication: Protected EAP (PEAP)
Anonymous Identity: <leave blank>
CA Certificate: <see below>
PEAP version: Automatic
Inner authentication: MSCHAPv2
Username: <your full university username e.g. usercode@someuni.ac.uk>
Password: <your university password>
```

Under the CA Certificate field, select the folder Icon and navigate to the location of your certificate store.

In Ubuntu (and Linux Mint) this is located in `/etc/ssl/certs`

Select the `QuoVadis_Root_CA_2.pem` certificate.

Additionally, try waiting a little while for the password change to propagate, try your old password in case it didn't change properly (changing your password again can sometimes force these things to sync if they failed) and also see if you can connect using another device like your mobile phone, then you'll have a better idea of whether it's really your laptop or the credentials you're using.

Edit: As I've just found out, eduroam is not UK specific so my confidence in these settings being consistent across establishments is now somewhat diminished.

Comment: Note that the CA certificate may change based on the given network - it might be a different certificate, and it is also possible that MSCHAP and PEAP is not in use (for Penn State, for instance, we have an eduroam network, but it's TTLS / PAP, not PEAP/MSCHAPv2).  Therefore, there should be a manual specific for each school/campus's network, there is no all inclusive "guide" for them al.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware there was an eduroam network over there too, that changes things somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a manual from your school to help you to connect to their network. I use the following instructions, but it might not be applicable to your school's network, because there are different settings for different networks.

1. Go to the wireless settings for setting up the connection.
2. Set:

   Wireless security: WPA and WPA2 Enterprise

   Authentication: Tunneled TLS

   CA Certificate: None

   Inner authentication: PAP

   Username/Password: YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD
3. Ignore the warning about the Certificate Authority.

   If this instruction does not work for you, you have to search for a specific instruction from your school.

Answer (score 0):

I just spend a couple of hours trying to troubleshoot my eduroam connection. To cut a long story short, the answer was to change from the Tunneled TLS to PEAP.

Try to look into your system logs to see whether you have the following messages:

```
wlan0: dissassociated from ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl (Reason: 23)
```

To check this, run the following command from terminal:

```
dmesg | grep "disassociated"
```

If yes, chances are that changing from TLS to PEAP will help.