# Unable to connect to university wifi on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

I've been trying for the past few days to connect to my university wifi and can't do it no matter what I try. I have tried these:

[Ubuntu 16.04 problems connecting to eduroam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788472/ubuntu-16-04-problems-connecting-to-eduroam)

[How to connect to WPA2/PEAP/MSCHAPv2 enterprise wifi networks that don't use a CA_Certificate, like Eduroam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/how-to-connect-to-wpa2-peap-mschapv2-enterprise-wifi-networks-that-dont-use-a-c)

[Cannot connect to WPA2/WPA Enterprise (PEAP and MSCHAP)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285234/cannot-connect-to-wpa2-wpa-enterprise-peap-and-mschap)

[HOWTO: Wireless Security - WPA1, WPA2, LEAP, etc.](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=202834)

and a couple of others that got lost in my browsing history. I can connect normally on windows and on my smartphone. I also can connect to my home network perfectly (on Ubuntu). I've got no clue on what exactly the problem is and being a linux novice certainly doesn't help. What I know for sure (because I can see on the Android configuration) is that the network uses PEAP and I don't need a CA certificate or Anonymous identity.

Edit: Let me clarify. I enter my credentials or edit the network configuration. The network appears as remembered. If I double click it will start connecting and after some time it will ask for my username and password again, like the first time. No error message or anything.

Comment: Have you contacted your university help desk?

Comment: You're probably facing this nasty bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1748839

Comment: @pomsky if that is the case I will have to wait for a solution to the bug, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot downgrade wpa\_supplicant to fix Wifi connection to a corporate network (WPA2) in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046810/cannot-downgrade-wpa-supplicant-to-fix-wifi-connection-to-a-corporate-network-w)

Answer (score 2):

#### A workaround using your smartphone

While it may not be working for all smartphones, here is a workaround that works for my LG G5.

1. Connect your smartphone with the university WiFi
2. Share your smartphone's internet (Setting>Network>Tethering)
3. Choose either USB tethering or Bluetooth tethering.
4. Do not choose Wi-Fi hotspot as your smartphone cannot connect to a WIFI network and act as hotspot at the same time.

Comment: I am sorry but this answer is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Ubuntu 18.04 as is explained in this thread - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1748839

It has been fixed in the upstream of Ubuntu 18.04. So if you have been keeping your Ubuntu updated, the fix must be present in your system.

Just go to Wifi settings and click on **Forget Connection** for the network in consideration. Start afresh and you should be all good.